# Casting DIRECTLY from iTunes to ChromeCast

Tags: audio, itunes

I just got my surround sound system working with bass boost, and I want to cast music from iTunes. Is there a way I can do this?

I have Windows 10, Kali Linux and Ubuntu on my laptop, and a ChromeCast setup to my TV, with my surround sound system setup to that.